# Why I was banned from chat?

Tags: support, chat, sock-puppets, deleted-users

I am a new user. I got chat access today after  [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343124/oops-something-bad-happened-in-chat), I don't know why I was banned in chat for 75 days.

May I know the reason?

[image]

Comment: Did you do something wrong like flags things that should not be flagged?

Comment: No. i didn't flagged any...

Comment: Or recreate an account to evade a chat ban…?

Comment: as deceze said did you have a previous account that was banned?

Comment: I didn't recreate this is different ID. and it is new

Comment: So you used to have a different account then?

Comment: If you had another account and it was banned, SO is able to link them in order to avoid evading the ban by creating another account.

Comment: yes. But i didn't do any wrong things with this account.

Comment: Note : apparently his account was deleted, maybe from his own request or by SO : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343124/oops-something-bad-happened-in-chat/ So let's wait for someone that can look for that.

Comment: Creating a new account to get out of a suspension is doing something wrong.

Comment: @Thamizhanda: "*yes. But i didn't do any wrong things with this account.*" If you did something wrong with your old account, they're not going to just forget about it because you got a new one.

Comment: @Thamizhanda: Out of curiosity, are you text in Tamil in the chat?

Comment: Well, these questions are always fun! The usual song-and-dance of denial in the comments, until a moderator comes and spills the beans. A great way to break up the monotony of a weekday morning!

Comment: @Arulkumar No i didn't text in tamil with this account

Comment: @Thamizhanda but if you chatted in Tamil on another account, got that account banned, then tried to just move your account here... the ban won't just go away... you are actively trying to play with different accounts to get access to a system you were banned for... can't you see how it is wrong?

Comment: @Tanner i didn't changed the car. i just changed the driver. fine. right?

Comment: Its the same car, I just changed my voice! .. You recognized me, didn't you? It's me Mario!

Comment: "Now i got it. I had one old user in this same email id and it was deleted. Now i created this user using that same email id after one year. is this the issue? – Thamizhanda 5 hours ago " From the other Meta question. I assume there's something going around with the mail used. If it's really after one year, I'm surprised the ban is still active that's said, wait for a moderator to clear that up.

Comment: yes i'm waiting for the moderator

Comment: I was really struggling (especially with the context vanished to pruning) with how to parse "i just changed the driver" because what a silly thing to say! 
 that just obviously doesn't hash with the (inferred) metaphor, right?  you're still the same person!  but then I realized--that's because they're using [polysemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy).  they're trying to tell you that _they've changed..._ `*wipes tear*` beautiful

Answer (score 53):

Your account is a sock puppet of another user, and this account was originally deleted due to voting fraud. That's why [this happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343124/oops-something-bad-happened-in-chat) when you recreated your account and attempted to use it to return to chat. The stub of the old chat account had become detached from the deleted account and reattached to your recreated one.

Your main account repeatedly refused to listen to a moderator who requested they stick to English in chat. The last time this happened, this other user (you) threatened this moderator in your native language. This led to that user being suspended from chat.

Immediately afterward, this account was recreated, and received [a very suspicious series of votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7526926/thamizhanda?tab=reputation) that just got you above the reputation threshold to use chat. It was clear this was an attempt to work around the other account being suspended from chat, so the account you're using now was also suspended from chat.

If we have any indication that this is once again being used to defraud the voting system, or that there is any other interaction between these two accounts, we will destroy this account in a manner that prevents its recreation and will suspend your main account. You're lucky we've let you get away with this much.

Comment: This probably gets old for you guys, but for the rest of us non-mods, it never does. It's so fun to read these...

Comment: @Mysticial - When I first became a moderator and started reading through annotations and messages, a whole lot of things suddenly made sense.

Comment: @Mysticial: We know. It is for that reason it never gets old for me either.

Comment: *You're lucky we've let you get away with this much.* I realize this is probably selection bias but it really does seem like y'all are nicer than you need to be.

Comment: @Mysticial a shame these things don't happen on Mondays. would be a great read to start off the working week